# Tkinter shortcuts in context menu on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter, contextmenu

I a have a menu that I display as a context menu in a `tkinter` application:

```
rmenu = tk.Menu(None, tearoff=0, takefocus=0)
# add some commands here
rmenu.add_command(label="Copy", copyfunction, accelerator="Shift-C")
rmenu.bind("<Shift-KeyPress-C>", copyfunction)                       # this doesn't work on windows!
```

I define a shortcut for a command in this context menu, and then, when I try to run the command by typing `<Shift>`+`<C>` on **windows** it doesn't work. Actually, I get a beep.

Is there a way to define shortcut in this situation?

### Update:

I have even tried to generate a event in the program using:

```
rmenu.event_generate("<Shift-KeyPress-C>", when="tail")
```

But the function `copyfunction` wasn't called.

PS: This works on Linux

Answer (score 2):

`bind` the keyboard shortcut to the `root`. Only things with `focus` listen for key bindings. How often does the context menu have focus? By using `bind_all` on the `root`, whatever has `focus` will trigger the key binding.

```
root.bind_all("<Shift-C>", copyfunction)
```

Comment: Actuelly the menu gets focus just after creation, then the user can click on it using teh mouse or use shortcut.
I tried `bind_all` but still get beeps!
I think it's not a focus problem.

Comment: @ThunderPheonix ~ So you DO want to open the menu before using the shortcut?

Comment: I don't think you can do that on windows. The 'ding' is essentially saying "I can't do this while this menu is open". Generally the point of a keyboard shortcut is so you don't have to open menus. I can't think of a single program that expects you to open a menu before you use a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: For example Firefox, you have the `Q` shortcut to inspect elements in the web page. You have to open the menu first than use the shortcut. This is just an example.